# Django ORM how to reference to another row in query?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following table 'book':

```
id     shelf   position (on shelf)
 1        2        3
 2        1        1
 3        1        2
 4        2        2
 5        2        1
```

I need to move  book4 to the end of shelf 1, therefore I need to set
 book4 position to [max(position) where shelf=1] + 1
 and position where position=[max(position) where shelf=2] to book4 initial position (to close the gap)

I tried this, but Max doesn't seem to work this way...

```
Book.objects.filter(shelf=2).annotate(max_position_on_shelf=Max('position'))\
                       .filter(position=F('max_position_on_shelf'))\
                       .update(position=F('max_position_on_shelf') + 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it more simple:

```
from django.db.models import Max

class Book(models.Model):
    ....

    def move(self, shelf_num):
        Book.objects.filter(shelf=self.shelf).order_by('-position')[:1].update(position=self.position)
        self.position = Book.objects.filter(shelf=shelf_num).aggregate(Max('position')) + 1
        self.save()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but isn't it good only for small tables? I mean your decrementing approach (__gt=), won't it be taxing for millions of rows? I'd really appreciate an advice tuned for perfomance :)

Comment: yes, it's bad to performance. But as I understand your question it's compulsory requirement to shift books to close the gap.

Comment: If you have really big tables, it would be better not to shift books, just set position to moved book to max_in_shelf+1

Comment: the order does not matter, It will be ok if the gap will be closed with the last book like so (2nd book gone to another shelf): 1 [gap] 3 4 -> 1 2(former 4) 3 - is there a way to do this?

Comment: If the order does not matter does it need to be stored?  If not then just change the shelf id of a book and save it.  Done.

Comment: what if you want to pick a random book, you need the order and no gaps (order_by('?') is not good for performance)

Comment: I have edited answer to your requirement to fill gap by book from same shelf with max position. It will be better for performance cause you have to edit only two rows in database. Please also check that you have database index on shelf and position fields.

Comment: thats what I needed! thank you very much! Btw you can use [0] instead of [:1]

Comment: Thanks!! Saved the day

Answer (score 1):

This would allow you to move a book to any position

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...

    def move(self, new_position):
        current_position = self.position

        # No move
        if current_position == new_position:
            return

        # Move book "left" (to a lower position number)
        elif current_position > new_position:  # 4 -> 2
            move = 1
            start = new_position  # 2
            end = current_position  # 4

        #Move book "right" (to a higher position number)
        else:  # 2 -> 4
            move = -1
            start = current_position  # 2
            end = new_position  # 4

        Books.objects.filter(
            shelf=self.shelf,
            position__gte=start,
            position__lte=end,
        ).exclude(
            pk=self.pk  # Move this manually
        ).update(
            position=F('position') + move
        )

        self.position = new_position
        self.save()
```

Comment: tnx, but it seems that your example is moving the book within a shelf, whether I need to change the shelf and to close position gaps caused by this movement...